# Binomial distribution with changing success probabilities

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

I have a sequence of $15$ experiments and I want to know the probability $S_1$ of success of each experiment so that the overall probability to obtain $10$ successes in the $15$ experiments run equals $P_1$.
To do so, I use binomial distribution and I am able to determine $S_1$ quite easily.

Now I want to add $7$ more *different* experiments for a total of $22$ *heterogeneous* experiments and have an overall probability of obtaining $11$ successes of $P_2$.
How can I determine the probability of success $S_2$ of the $7$ new experiments in order to have the probability $P_2$ of obtaining $11$ successes over $22$ experiments, given that the first $15$ experiments have success probability of $S_1$?

Comment: Not following.  Why do I need to refer back to the original $15$ experiments?  I just want $11$ successes out of $22$, so (if I know the probability of a single success) I can just use the binomial distribution. Or am I not understanding?

Comment: Oh, are you saying the extra $7$ experiments are somehow different?  In that case you will need to use the binomial theorem in each block and add over pairs $(a,b)$ with $a+b=11$.

Comment: Yes the `7` extra experiments are different, because their success rate can be completely different from the first `15`'s one. But then the question is "whats the probability that doing the first 15 experiments and then the 7 more experiments, I get 11 overall successes?". Can you explain the "add over pairs" part better as I can't seem to understand what you say well... thanks a lot.

Comment: Well, there are lots of ways to get $11$ successes out of $22$.  I can get $4$ out of the first $15$ and $7$ out of the last $7$, for instance.  That has probability $\binom {15}4\times S_1^4\times (1-S_1)^{11}\times S_2^7$.  And so on, for each pair $(4,7), (5,6), (6,5), \cdots$.  You'll get a degree $7$ polynomial in $S_2$ which I suggest you solve numerically.

Comment: A suggestion:  edit your post for clarity.  Why make your readers deduce that the new experiments are different from the old?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I guess that's the only right way to go.

Comment: Yeah, I seriously doubt there is a short cut here....but the numerical calculation shouldn't be too bad.

Comment: My problem is that it's gonna keep for longer than 2 "batches", but it keeps going with 7 more different experiments with 34 successes needed, then 7 more with 45 successes needed and so on for 20 total "batches" of different experiments. So the calculations start to seem quite out of hand.

Comment: Well, you are doing this on a computer, I assume?  Shouldn't be that bad if you have a modest number of batches.  The partition number is binomial so that will start to grow on you as the number of batches and the target success number increases.

Comment: Yes, if I can figure out some sorta recursive algorithm I can program the heck out of it. I think my problem is I cannot get to see the whole picture of what I'm trying to do to turn it in recursive steps.

Comment: I'd say the programming issue was listing the partitions in a standard way.  That is, if you have $B$ batches and want $S$ successes then you need to enumerate all $B-$tuples of non-negative integers which add to $S$ (and which pass various size constraints). Standard Stars and Bars problem, which (I assume) has been thoroughly optimized for code.  Once you have that, then I think getting the polynomial you need to work with shouldn't be too ugly.

Comment: Gonna try that stright on, thanks